# LINQ: why array and list uses different iterators

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

The question is: why does it use this code

```
  if (source is TSource[])
    return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>((TSource[]) source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
  if (source is List<TSource>)
    return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>((List<TSource>) source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
  else
    return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
}
```

instead of

```
  if (source is IList<TSource>)
    return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectIListIterator<TSource, TResult>((List<TSource>) source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
  return (IEnumerable<TResult>) new Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, (Func<TSource, bool>) null, selector);
}
```

i mean `List<T>` and `T[]` both implements `IList<T>` and they both has indexer and implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so they both can be iterated in the same singular manner, but now uses different iterators.

Comment: From where are you getting these code snippets?

Comment: I would imagine that under the hood when these iterators are used, LINQ can make reasonable optimizations - and may not be iterating them in the exact same manner. But without digging up LINQ source I can't prove this, just a strong hunch (ergo, a comment)

Comment: @payo http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply an optimization that covers the extremely common cases of filtering an array or list.

1. WhereSelectArrayIterator doesn't use the underlying enumerator of the array - it uses the *indexer*. From a performance standpoint, it's preferable to use the array-indexer directly than go through the `IList<T>` indexer or use the enumerator.
2. WhereSelectListIterator does use the enumerator of the list, but because it "knows" the type of the `List<TSource>` enumerator to be the *struct* `List<TSource>.Enumerator` (which it can retrieve using the special GetEnumerator method on `List<TSource>` separate from the interface method), it avoids boxing the enumerator on the heap - which you would necessarily have to do if you used `IEnumerator<TSource>`.
3. WhereSelectEnumerableIterator is the general case that uses the backing `IEnumerator<TSource>` of the source - it will work for all kinds of sequences, but without any special optimizations. If the enumerator happens to be a struct, tough luck - it will be boxed.

Comment: Yeah, i got it some minutes ago. So if the same idea comes comes to different people in the same time, probably it's right.